# How did Tobias end up as a registered sex offender?

Tags: arrested-development

In the Season 4 episode of *Arrested Development*, Tobias is caught by a *To Catch A Predator* style show when he thinks he's going to meet Maeby at home. It's not clear from the episode how he became the target for the show, unless I've missed something important. Is this just a coincidence, or explained in a later episode? Is there even an explanation?

Comment: He was an official [*Analrapist*](http://i.imgur.com/8IWo4.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

**It was simply a matter of Tobias being in the wrong place at the wrong time**. He walked into the sting operation and said:

> "Is there a little girl in here? Daddy needs to get his rocks off."

He's simply referring to his daughter when he says "little girl", and is indicating he needs help getting his rock suit off, as he was impersonating The Thing. Unfortunately, it came off as he was actually entering the house looking for a little girl to "get his rocks off", which is an [idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom) for "ejaculate".

As such the crew thought he was entering the house to have sex with a little girl, as they were set up to run a sting operation to catch pedophiles. Tobias had no knowledge of this prior to entering the house.

Tobias has a history of saying [double entendres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre), where he means one thing, but what he said has another, often sexual connotation that someone might think he means instead, but Tobias never realizes this.

Comment: To add to what MattD has said, Tobias *wasn't* a 'target' for the show: the show was using the model home as a set for their trap. This was because Maebe had rented the model home to the crew of the show (remember: She is a Film/TV exec), so, as Matt has said, Tobias believed he was coming home to see Maebe, and the crew assumed he was a peadophile, in no small part due to his language.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional I think this is real answer to the question, which was why the TV crew was there in the first place.